# Web3.utils.hexToUtf8 getting "undefined" error

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, web3js, drizzle

I am trying to return an username from a struct inside a mapping and I am getting this error:
Error: The parameter "undefined" must be a valid HEX string.

```
contract UserStorage is BaseStorage {

    event UserCreated(string _message);

    struct Profile {
        uint userId;
        bytes32 username;
      }

    mapping(address => Profile) public profiles;
    mapping(address => bool) public addresses;
    mapping (bytes32 => uint) public usernames;


    uint latestUserId = 0;

    function createUser(
        address _address,
        bytes32 _username
        ) public onlyControllerAddr returns(uint) {

        latestUserId++;

        profiles[_address] = Profile(
        latestUserId,
        _username
        );

  

        addresses[_address] = true;
        usernames[_username] = latestUserId;

        emit UserCreated("Membership Confirmed");
        return latestUserId;
    }

}
```

```
class UserAccount extends React.Component {
 state = { dataKey: null };

componentDidMount() {
   const { drizzle, drizzleState } = this.props;
   const contract = drizzle.contracts.UserStorage;
   const account = drizzleState.accounts[0];
  
                                                        
  const dataKey = contract.methods['profiles'].cacheCall(account);
  this.setState({ dataKey });

 }


 render() {
  
   const { UserStorage } = this.props.drizzleState.contracts;
   const displayData = UserStorage.profiles[this.state.dataKey];
   const user =  displayData && displayData.value[1];
   const username = Web3.utils.hexToUtf8(user);
   console.log(user);
   return (
   <div>Hello: {user}</div>
   )
 }
}

export default UserAccount;
```

Here are values that are returned:

```
user:
0x426f620000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

const displayData:
{args: Arguments(1), fnIndex: 6, value: Result, error: null}args: Arguments ["0x1C16e11e45Ae1601186E05EE64f38276FAb2239a", callee: (...), Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]error: nullfnIndex: 6value: Result {0: "1", 1: "0x426f620000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", userId: "1", username: "0x426f620000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you edit the question? It is unclear what you are asking or what is the actual error or what is happening?

Comment: The problem is that `displayData` is undefined, meaning the value isn't available yet. You will have to display some placeholder until it is ready.